# Create Array from rows in DataGridView containing commas separated values. VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview

I have a list of strings arrays that I have hardcoded. Instead of hardcoding these strings I would like to get them from my datagridview. My datagridview only contains one column which is filled with rows containing data like "2, 5590045752, 1000, Supplier,40000, ,7/31/2013". Is there a way to split the values in each row from the datagridview and put them into Dim Data As New List(Of String()).

```
Private Sub btnExtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExtract.Click


    **Dim Data As New List(Of String()) From {
            "2, 5590045752, 1000, Supplier,40000, ,7/31/2013".Split(","c),
            "2,5590045752,1001,Factory,27000, ,2/28/2014".Split(","c),
            "2,5590045752,1002,Electric Company,90000, ,4/28/2014".Split(","c)
    }**

    Dim Results As New List(Of Demo)
    For Each Item In Data
        Results.Add(New Demo(Item))
    Next


    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\Sample.txt")
        For Each Item In Results
            sw.WriteLine("D9655590045752       " + Item.ToString)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Demo
    Public Property Col1 As String
    Public Property Col2 As String
    Public Property Col3 As String
    Public Property Col4 As String
    Public Property Col5 As String
    Public Property Col6 As String
    Public Property Col7 As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' No assertion done that determines
    ''' if the correct amount of elements are passed
    ''' in. 
    ''' 
    ''' You can do whatever is needed i.e trim as done
    ''' below or perhaps do the padding here rather
    ''' than in the .ToString method.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByVal sender As String())
        Col1 = sender(0).Trim
        Col2 = sender(1).Trim
        Col3 = sender(2).Trim
        Col4 = sender(3).Trim
        Col5 = sender(4).Trim
        Col6 = sender(5).Trim
        Col7 = sender(6).Trim
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Col3.PadLeft(9, "0"c) & "0000" & Col5 & Col7.Replace("/", "")
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your issue? We are not here to write the code for you.

Comment: I recently updated my post to include code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. Replace the code in surrounded by stars (**) to this:

```
Dim Data As New List(Of String())
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
   If r.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
      Data.Add(r.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split(","c))
   End If
Next
```

With DataGridView1 changed to your DataGridView name.

Comment: I used your code and I received the following error when I ran it, "NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Can you display your updated code, because this works fine for me.

Comment: Wops, terribly sorry. I did my tests on a DGV that did not have the Allow user to add rows option enabled. This issue is caused by that. I  updated the code for you. Now it works fine.